# How do I run tasks in the background using Django?

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, celery

I have an end-point in Django which initiates a function which takes really long to complete. I don't want the request to wait until this function has been completed.

```
def MyRequest(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args **kwargs):
        a_function_which_takes_really_long_time()
        return Response({"message" : "We're Working on it."})
```

I tried using asyncio with [Django Asynchronous Support](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/async/). Also tried python threading here. But all these are making the request to wait until the function is completed.

I know that we can easily achieve this using Celery. But that approach would require me to use a message-broker such as Redis, RabbitMQ or any other similar servers which I'm not supposed to use.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion using celery with django is really easy and recommended. I am not sure why are you against using a message broker, both of the options you suggested are really stable and wildly used projects.

But, if you still have the broker constraint I can recommend [apscheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) which doesn't use an intermediate broker